# Road and candidiate problem

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

The city has n districts and n - 1 bidirectional roads. We know that from any district there is a path along the roads to any other district. Let's enumerate all districts in some way by integers from 1 to n, inclusive. Furthermore, for each road the residents decided if it is the problem road or not. A problem road is a road that needs to be repaired.

There are n candidates running the elections. Let's enumerate all candidates in some way by integers from 1 to n, inclusive. If the candidate number i will be elected in the city Parliament, he will perform exactly one promise — to repair all problem roads on the way from the i-th district to the district 1, where the city Parliament is located.

I have to find the subset of candidates such that if all candidates from the subset will be elected to the city Parliament, all problem roads in the city will be repaired. If there are several such subsets, i want the subset consisting of the minimum number of candidates.

EXAMPLE : 
Say if n=5
And we have problem roads between (1,2) , (2,3) , (3,4) , (4,5)
Then if we choose 5th candidate then all roads will be prepaired.
Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a rooted tree: the $n$ districts are the nodes (vertices), and the root is district $1$. Thus, there is a unique shortest path from each node to the root. Let $v$ be a leaf of the tree; there is a unique road from $v$ to another district. If that road needs repair, you definitely need to include $v$ in your set. If it is in good repair, remove it and $v$, and consider the subtree that remains.